# PHP Script won't run on command line

Tags: php, command-line-interface, daemon, gremlin

The Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
while(true){
    $rate_limit = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json'),true); # Check how many API calls remain

    $wait = round(3600/150);
    # *** IMPORTANT ***
    # Twitter limits API calls to 150/hr so regardless of the number of handles, we can only make one request every 24 seconds (which is 3600/150).
    # As a result, it takes one hour to run through 150 handles one time each.  Since we'll probably never monitor that many, each handle may get updated multiple times an hour.

    # Establish the database connection
    if(!$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','twitterd','password','twitterd')){
        file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Cannot connect to the database');
        break;
    }

    $get_handles = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT `handle` FROM twitter_handles"); # Grab the Twitter handles from the database

    #  Append them to the $handles array
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_handles,MYSQLI_NUM)){
        $handles[] = $row[0];
    }

    #  Check the remaining API calls
    if($rate_limit['remaining_hits']<count($handles)){
        file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Rate limit reached', FILE_APPEND);
        sleep(600);
        continue;
    }else{
        # Loop through the $handles values, make an API call, and insert the tweets.
        foreach($handles as $value){
            file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Processing ' . $value . '\'s data...' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); # Tell the log what we're doing

            $user_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:' . $value . '&rpp=100&include_entities=1'),true); # Get the handle's timeline and put it into $user_data
            $user_data = $user_data['results']; # Put only the results index (tweets) into into $user_data

            if(count($user_data)<1){
                file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' No data for ' . $value . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            }

            for($i=0;$i<count($user_data);$i++){
                # Lazy method for sanitizing variables
                $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['id']);
                $created_at = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['created_at']);
                $from_user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user_id']);
                $profile_image_url = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['profile_image_url']);
                $from_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user']);
                $from_user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['from_user_name']);
                $text = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$user_data[$i]['text']);

                $needles = array('hack','tango down','dump','breach','data');

                # Check the tweet relevance
                foreach($needles as $needle){
                    $needle = '/' . $needle . '/i'; # So we don't have to manually type out the regex

                    # Make a call based on the tweet contents
                    if(preg_match($needle,$text) == 0){
                        file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' No relevant tweet data in tweet #' . $id .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                    }else{
                        file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Processing tweet #' . $id .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
                        $insert_tweets = "INSERT INTO tweets (`id`,`created_at`,`from_user_id`,`profile_image`,`from_user`,`from_user_name`,`text`) VALUES ('{$id}','{$created_at}','{$from_user_id}','{$profile_image_url}','{$from_user}','{$from_user_name}','{$text}');";
                        mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert_tweets);
                    }
                }
            }
            file_put_contents('tweet_gremlin.log', date('r') . ' Sleeping for ' . $wait . ' seconds before processing the next handle' .PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
            sleep($wait);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
?>
```

If I run this on the command line like this:

```
./tweet_gremlin.php
```

It runs fine.  But if I run it like this:

```
./tweet_gremlin.php &
```

It does nothing.  I cannot figure out why.

EDIT: I had to take out pretty much all of the code because it wouldn't let me submit it all.

Comment: When you say "it does nothing," what do you mean? Have you done a `ps` on the command-line to verify that it's not running? The `&` tells the terminal to run that process in the background which is helpful if you want to start multiple GUI-driven programs, but doesn't help much if you're running PHP scripts.

Comment: try running:  `php ./tweet_gremlin.php`

Comment: The ampersand (&) means run the task in the background.  Now, if it prompts for input, it's going to block and stop running until you bring it to the foreground.

Comment: In that second scenario, you a launching the process into the background are you sure it is not running?

Comment: It runs in the background, but doesn't execute any of the code in the while() loop.  It doesn't require any user input.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't execute your code? What is this code supposed to do? Show us some of the code you put inside your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a background job with the ampersand.

Depending on the underlying OS the background job changes to status "Stopped" because it wants to read from STDIN and/or wants to write to STDOUT.

Enter  `jobs` into the same terminal after starting `./tweet_gremlin.php &`
This tells your job's status.

If the job's status is "Stopped"  discard STDOUT+STDERR and STDIN: `./tweet_gremlin.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

If your script runs now you need to handle STDIN and/or STDOUT+STDERR differently in `./tweet_gremlin.php &`
E.g. write to a logfile instead of STDOUT+STDERR.

You can also test the behavior of your terminal.
The following creates a PHP error on STDERR due to a missing semicolon:

```
php -r 'echo "backgrounding sucks\n"' &
jobs
fg1
```

The follwing creates normal output on STDOUT:

```
php -r 'echo "backgrounding sucks\n";' &
jobs
fg1
```

If you cannot fix the issue in your code, look into your terminal's settings. Watch out for stty tostop (the SIGTTOU signal)

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  I ran your tests and when running ./tweet_gremlin.php & the job was indeed stopped.  If I set in the script `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `error_log(E_ALL, 3, "tweet_gremlin.log")` will that alleviate the need to run the script as `./tweet_gremlin.php </dev/null &>/dev/null &`?

Comment: The goal is not to produce any output on STDOUT and STDERR.
I am not deep enough into PHP CLI to say how to achive this.
You need to investigate yourself.  

error_log() handles just one individual error message. But you need to handle all error messages and exceptions.  
set_error_handler() might be a starting point.  
Or suppress errors completely by setting error_reporting 0 and catch all exceptions.

Comment: He, he stackoverflow to the rescue:
Redirecting STD* in PHP is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823015/1574876)
This is the way to go! Only drawback is that it will on Unix-like OS only. But hey ...