# Save file in some specific location using content disposition

Tags: php, content-disposition

Below code works perfectly to download the `.html` file of a current PHP web page

```
$filename = 'filename.html';
header('Content-disposition: inline; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-type: text/html');
```

Is there any way to save file in some specific location instead the download response.

**Ex:** if i want to save this `filename.html` file in location `/export/www/html/myproject/var/htmlpages`

**Tried below logic as alternative also:**

```
ob_start();
file_put_contents('myfile.html', ob_get_contents());
```

But its generating empty file

Comment: not sure if I understood your question. the client/user-agent download it where he wants

Comment: I need to put current page html content in this file. And don't want to use $html = file_get_contents('my-domain.com.');

Comment: I saw content disposition works well. Don't want user to get the download request. Instead if it can save internally in some location. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect STDOUT to a file in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937627/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-php)

Comment: Earlier tried this one also but it's generating empty file.

Comment: of course it generate an empty file. you should start with `ob_start`, then you print what you want in the file, and only then you call `ob_get_contents`.

Answer (score 1):

Use fopen() to write a file in a specific directory instead of download response like:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');    // here you can pass the directory path + filename
fwrite($fp, '1');
fwrite($fp, '23');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

[fwrite() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: I need to put current page html content in this file. And don't want to use $html = file_get_contents('http://my-domain.com.'); Please suggest any alternative.