Redirecting printf output to a file within a namespace in PHP
I am trying to redirect the output of printf to a file. I referred to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3823015/2704265
However, I am working within a namespace:
namespace dnip_ail;

// Redirect the output to a file
fclose(STDOUT);
$STDOUT = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . '/log.txt', 'wb');

This code results in an "Undefined constant 'dnip_ail\STDOUT'" error.
If I use:
fclose(\STDOUT);

I get an error:

Undefined constant 'STDOUT'

It seems like the "STDOUT" constant is not defined at all. How can I resolve this?

Are you using the CLI SAPI? STDOUT isn't available in the web environment.

@Barmar, I don't know that. I am in web environment. I just want to redirect the output of printf  to a file, since there are many printf in my PHP code and it is not convenient to modify them one by one. And I search online and get the StackOverflow solution to change the STDOUT.

That only works when running PHP from the command line, not in a web page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937627/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-php for solutions using ob_start().


Add below line of code after first first namespace

use \STDOUT;

